# Aligning 3 background images vertically

Tags: css, image

How do I make it so 3 images are next to each other with CSS?

Currently, my images aren't displaying properly.. This is the way it looks
http://i43.tinypic.com/2yzmomg.png

```
#container {
width: 960px;
margin: 150px auto 0;
text-align: left;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
border-right-style: solid;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-color: #b53913;
background:url('burger1.jpg'),url('burger2.jpg'),url('burger3.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
background-size:500px, 50px, 700px, 50px, 1200px, 50px
}
```

Comment: Add your html please.

Comment: oh my bad background images i thought they were image tags

Comment: Or, you can adjust the `background-position` for each individual background image.

Comment: Need it to be that there are 3 images next to eachother :P

Comment: But if you resize the window then the whole site gets messed up, doesnt it? @ Terry

Comment: You are looking for background-position: [http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp]

Comment: I still can;t get it to work.. Whatever way I adjust the settings it just won't go the way I want..

Answer (score 0):

you can use background position property with your image width. let say your image width is 200px then your code should look like below.

```
background-position: 0px 0px, 200px 0px, 400px 0px;
```